# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in Spacy Python

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I want to print `Parse Tree` using `Spacy`. But the code below is giving the error

> en_nlp = spacy.language('English')
>   TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

The error is on this `en_nlp = spacy.loads('en')` line. I tried to shake off as `en_nlp = spacy.language(English)` by importing `from spacy.en import English` But still it is not working. Can someone help?

Code:

```
import spacy
from nltk import Tree

en_nlp = spacy.loads('en')

doc = en_nlp("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")

def to_nltk_tree(node):
    if node.n_lefts + node.n_rights > 0:
        return Tree(node.orth_, [to_nltk_tree(child) for child in node.children])
    else:
        return node.orth_


[to_nltk_tree(sent.root).pretty_print() for sent in doc.sents]
```

Comment: From the error, `spacy.language` is a module, not a callable method

Comment: Try using spacy.load('en') without the 's'

Comment: @mpurg Still not working without 's'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it spacy.load('en') or spacy.loads('en') ?

The official doc https://spacy.io/docs/ says : 
    spacy.load('en').
    It may be the problem.

Comment: what is the error when you replace spacy.loads by spacy.load() ?

Comment: OMG I got this `RuntimeError: Model 'en' not installed. Please run 'python -m spacy.en.download' to install latest compatible model.
` Now I am installing . Will be back in a sec.